# FloatingActionButton not being displayed in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using this `https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button` in my application. I have a fragment that displays a google map. This button displays fine on all versions of android 4.xx, but on android version 5.xx it is invisible.

This is the xml of the button in my fragment:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnShifts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/fab_plus24" />
```

The library is bing injected correctly in my application because the button does work in earlier versions of android. Do any of you have any idea of what could be going wrong? Any reason why it wouldn't work in android 5.xx?

Thank you in advance, this is a issue I'm having a lot of trouble with. Let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) library.It is Updated to API 22 and Build Tools 22